# How dose umbraco find its index? Umbraco 8.0

Tags: content-management-system, umbraco

My Problem

how can i change my defult site in umbraco?

My goal.

allways open index as my defult site.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In umbraco backend - right click on the Content node to sort the nodes and make "index" node the first one and that should do it.

Comment: Thanks it worked. is the first site always the top one? @Davor

Comment: @KristianF yes - or you can change it by clicking on "Culture and Hostnames" and providing the domain. In your case you can set localhost:49916 as the domain on any node you want and it would be the first page that is served.